# findOneAndUpdate with condition

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update a record based on condition:

```
Product.findOneAndUpdate({
        number: fields.number[0]
    }, {
        category: fields.category[0],
        name: fields.name[0]
    },
    function(err, product) {


    });
```

So, I want to check if fields.category is present then update else do not update the original value.

```
fields.category ? fields.category[0] : ""
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After little search, found that I need to use `findOne` method and update based on property

```
Product.findOne({number: fields.number[0]}, function (err, product) {
    product.category = fields.category ? fields.category[0] : product.category;
    product.name = fields.name[0];

    product.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
    });
});
```